# text-align:center not centering text

Tags: css

I'm wondering how I can center the glyphs in this page, they are an icon-font using @font-face, but even after I apply text-align:center to the anchors that contain each glyph, they are not centering.

They appear left-aligned.

Any idea on how to fix them to make them centered?

I would prefer a solution that does not involve css3's flexbox.

Here is the page: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/270523/help/initializr/index.html

Also if you could center the last line of text in the header, #navigationText, I would greatly appreciate that as that doesn't seem centered either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove `float:left` from `.nav ul li`. `text-align:center` will center all children that are `display:inline` and aren't floating.

```
.nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block;` in the `.nav ul` class... it will be at center automatically...

```
.nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```